# Assign a value to a static text in GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, uicontrol

How can I assign a value to a static text in a MATLAB GUI?

Answer (score 21):

Double click on your text in guide to open the property editor, then edit the `'String'` property. You can also set the `'Tag'` property so you can edit it while your GUI is running. If you set your tag to `mytext`, you can change the static text to `'MyString'` with the following line:

```
set(handles.mytext,'String','MyString')
```

Answer (score 0):

So that didn't work for me. However, after setting the tag as above the following would work:

```
set(findobj('Tag','mytext'),'String','MyString')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, considering that **name** and **last_name** are global, just for example:

```
<code>
global name last_name 
var1 = findobj(gcbf,'Tag','nomb');
var2 = findobj(gcbf,'Tag','ap');

data1 = char(name);
data2 = char(last_name);

set (var1, 'String', data1 );
set (var2, 'String', data2 );
</code>
```

Also consider thatr **nomb** and **ap** are Static Text